# Running a shell utility from my app causes it to use 100% CPU

Tags: java, android

This is sort of an odd one:

I am trying to run a terminal command from my android app. The command launches a small linux utility that runs in the background. When I launch it from a terminal emulator it works fine, with no unusual CPU activity, but when I run the same command from my app, the utility that it launches uses a ton of CPU. Also, another process (system/bin/logcat2) shows up and starts using a bunch of CPU as well.

Here is the code I am using to issue the shell commands:

```
 void execCommandLine(String command)
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

        try
        {
            proc = runtime.exec("su");
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
            osw.write(command);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {

            Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command resulted in an IO Exception: " + command);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (osw != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    osw.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e){}
            }
        }

        try 
        {
            proc.waitFor();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){}

        if (proc.exitValue() != 0)
        {

            Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command returned error: " + command + "\n  Exit code: " + proc.exitValue());
        }
    }
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running 'just' su is not going to be very helpful (it will default to being interactive)

If the problem persists with another test command, like ls, you may want to

```
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

first

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not just running "su" I am passing a command to the method which is run after "su" has been executed. Can you explain the code snippet you posted a bit further?